# How to make the original picturebox and the cropped picturebox to be relative?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the code found here:
[How to crop a section of an Image at cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128394/7444103)

The original picturebox the big picturebox on the right size is 600,400 and the left small cropped image size is 243,256 when the mouse is inside the image in the orginal picturebox the cropped image in the cropped picturebox is not the right cropped area.

I want that no matter what the original and the cropped pictureBoxes size are and the image size is that when moving the mouse inside the original picturebox it will show the right cropped lens area in the cropped picturebox.

another problems:

When changing the W and H of the lens size in runtime it's not changing.

When changing the radio buttons checked changed it's not changing the lens shape.

Also the relative size checkbox not changing much anything when checked/unchecked.

Screenshot of the form when running and the mouse is over the original pictureBox and what it's showing in the small cropped picturebox:

[image: cropped]

the form1 code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cropping_Images
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap sourceImage = null;
        RectangleF imageLens = RectangleF.Empty;
        Size lensPixelSize = new Size(100, 100);
        LensType lensType = LensType.Circular;
        bool lensUseRelativeSize = false;
        bool drawLens = false;

        private enum LensType
        {
            Circular,
            Rectangular
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBoxOriginal.Image = Image.FromFile(@"d:\Screenshots\rec1.jpg");
            sourceImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"d:\Screenshots\rec1.jpg"));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBoxOriginal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            imageLens.Location = GetLensPosition(e.Location, imageLens);
            imageLens.Size = lensUseRelativeSize
                           ? GetScaledLensSize(pictureBoxOriginal.ClientRectangle, sourceImage.Size, lensPixelSize)
                           : lensPixelSize;
            pictureBoxOriginal.Invalidate();
            pictureBoxCropped.Invalidate();
        }

        private PointF GetLensPosition(PointF centerPosition, RectangleF rect)
        {
            return new PointF(centerPosition.X - (rect.Width / 2),
                              centerPosition.Y - (rect.Height / 2));
        }

        private SizeF GetScaledLensSize(RectangleF canvas, SizeF imageSize, SizeF lensSize)
        {
            float scaleRatio = GetImageScaledRatio(canvas, imageSize);
            return new SizeF(lensSize.Width * scaleRatio, lensSize.Width * scaleRatio);
        }

        private float GetImageScaledRatio(RectangleF canvas, SizeF imageSize)
        {
            return Math.Max(canvas.Width, canvas.Height) /
                   Math.Max(imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
        }

        private RectangleF CanvasToImageRect(RectangleF canvas, SizeF imageSize, RectangleF rect)
        {
            float scaleRatio = GetImageScaledRatio(canvas, imageSize);
            return new RectangleF(new PointF(rect.X / scaleRatio, rect.Y / scaleRatio),
                                  new SizeF(rect.Width / scaleRatio, rect.Height / scaleRatio));
        }

        private void pictureBoxOriginal_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2.0f))
            {
                pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
                switch (lensType)
                {
                    case LensType.Circular:
                        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, Rectangle.Round(imageLens));
                        break;
                    case LensType.Rectangular:
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, Rectangle.Round(imageLens));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxCropped_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!drawLens) return;
            RectangleF section = CanvasToImageRect(pictureBoxOriginal.ClientRectangle, sourceImage.Size, imageLens);
            DrawImageSelection(e.Graphics, pictureBoxCropped.ClientRectangle, section, sourceImage);
        }

        private void DrawImageSelection(Graphics g, RectangleF canvas, RectangleF imageSection, Image image)
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(image, canvas, imageSection, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            switch (lensType)
            {
                case LensType.Circular:
                    using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
                    {
                        path.AddEllipse(canvas);
                        g.SetClip(path, CombineMode.Exclude);
                        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(160, Color.Black)))
                        {
                            g.FillRectangle(brush, canvas);
                            g.ResetClip();
                            using (var pen = new Pen(brush, 1f))
                                g.DrawEllipse(pen, canvas);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case LensType.Rectangular:
                    // NOP
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void checkBoxRelativeSize_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)       
            => lensUseRelativeSize = checkBoxRelativeSize.Checked;

        private void radioButtonCircularLens_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            => lensType = (LensType)(int.Parse((sender as Control).Tag.ToString()));

        private void pictureBoxOriginal_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            => drawLens = true;

        private void pictureBoxOriginal_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawLens = false;
            pictureBoxCropped.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post code that you took from anywhere, you have to mention the source. I've added that reference. You copied this code from here: [How to crop a section of an Image at cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128394/7444103) and slapped it into a Form. You probably didn't subscribe to events correctly -- That code assumes your app is DpiAware -- Don't use `Image.FromFile()` like that, you lose ICM information and lock the file on disk